# In infrared spectroscopy, why is there no C=C reading for E alkenes?

Tags: spectroscopy, ir-spectroscopy

For the (E)-2-pentene, there was no C=C reading, about 1600. For the (Z)-2-pentene, there is a C=C. Why is there a reading on the Z but not on the E?

Answer (score 12):

The $\ce{C=C}$ stretch is responsible for this ir peak. For an ir absorbtion to occur, the absorption must result in a change in dipole moment.  If we examine the $\ce{C=C}$ stretch in *cis*- and *trans*-2-butene we find that

[image]

[image source](http://socratic.org/questions/how-can-i-draw-cis-and-trans-isomers)

- *cis*-2-butene has a dipole moment (0.33 D) and upon stretching the double bond the dipole moment will change; therefore **we would expect** to see an ir peak for the $\ce{C=C}$ stretch in this molecule
- *trans*-2-butene does not have a dipole moment  (0 D) and upon stretching the double bond the dipole moment will remain zero, there is no change; therefore we **would not expect** to see an ir peak for the $\ce{C=C}$ stretch in this molecule

A general rule based on these dipole moment arguments is that, for symmetrically di-substituted olefins $\ce{C=C}$ stretches in *trans* olefins are non-existent or very weak, the absorption is much stronger in the *cis* isomers.

We can extend this reasoning to molecules with dipole moments, if the dipole moment is very small.  *Trans*-2-pentene does have a dipole moment but it is very small and it is less than the dipole moment in the *cis*-isomer **and** the dipole moment in the *trans*-isomer (being smaller to begin with)  will change less upon stretching the double bond than it will for the *cis* isomer.  Therefore we would expect a very weak absorption in *trans*-2-pentene, while the *cis* isomer should show a stronger absorption.